# Pymongo Aggregate with multiple conditions: lookup, unwind, redact, cond, sort and limit

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, lookup

```
done_status = ['BAD_PU', 'TO_WH', 'RCVDPORT', 'RCVD', 'BAD_DEL', 'MISSFLT', 'OFFLOAD']

shipments = db.db_shipment.aggregate([{
    "$lookup":{
        "from":"db_shipment_status_history",
        "localField":"_id",
        "foreignField":"fk_shipment_id",
        "as":"shipment_status_history_collection"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind":
        "$shipment_status_history_collection"},
        {"$redact":{"$cond":{ "$if": { "status_value": {"$in": done_status } } },
                "$then": "$$KEEP"
                ,"$else":"$$PRUNE"
                }
            },
        {"$sort":
            {'shipment_status_history_collection.rec_timestamp':-1}},
        {"$limit":1},
        {"$project":{"pkey":"$pkey","_code":"$_code"}}
    ])
```

error:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $cond: { $if: { status_value: { $in: [ "BAD_PU", "TO_WH", "RCVDPORT", "RCVD", "BAD_DEL", "MISSFLT", "OFFLOAD" ] } } }, $else: "$$PRUNE", $then: "$$KEEP" }

how to fix this error? Im trying to add the latest shipment status history in the shipment record where the status value is in the given status value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the redact stage for your aggregation pipeline. `if`, `then` and `else` are a part of the `$cond` operator and they're not operators in themselves.

Also, `$in` operator is passed an array where its first item is checked for presence in the second item. The second item is usually an iterable.

**Mongo 3.6**

```
messenger_pipeline_status = (
    messenger_active_status['data']['pending'] 
    + messenger_active_status['data']['processing']
)
assigned_status = ['DEL_ASSIGNED','PU_ASSIGNED']

subpipeline =  [
    {
        '$match': {
            '$expr': {
                '$and': [
                    {'$eq': ['$fk_shipment_id', '$$pkey']},
                    {'$eq': ['$fk_messenger_id', fk_user_id]},
                    {'$in': ['$status_value', assigned_status]}
                ]
            }                       
        }
    },

    {
        '$sort': {
            'rec_timestamp': -1
        }
    },

    {
        '$limit': 1
    },

    {
        '$project': {
            'fk_shipment_id': 1
        }
    }
]

pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {
            'status_value': {'$in': messenger_pipeline_status}
            'is_deleted': False,
            'is_postponed': False,
            'is_active': True,
        }
    },

    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'db_shipment_status_history',
            'let': {'pkey':  '$pkey'},
            'pipeline': subpipeline,
            'as': 'shipment_status_history'
        }
    },

    {
        '$match': {
            'shipment_status_history': {
               '$ne': [] 
            } 
        }
    },

    {
        '$unwind': '$shipment_status_history'
    },

    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'pkey': 1,
            '_code': 1,
            'date_created': 1,
            'sender_full_name': '$sender.full_name',
            'sender_raw_address': '$sender.raw_address',
            'sender_formatted_address': '$sender.formatted_address',
            'receiver_full_name': '$receiver.full_name',
            'receiver_raw_address': '$receiver.raw_address',
            'receiver_formatted_address': '$receiver.formatted_address',
            'status_name': 1,
            'team_value': 1,
            'cs_name': 1,
            'fk_messenger_id': '$shipment_status_history.fk_shipment_id'
        }
    }   
]

result = db.db_shipment.aggregate(pipeline)
print(list(result))
```

[Edit] **Mongo 3.2**

The following aggregation pipeline produces similar results as the above and is valid query for Mongo 3.2.

```
messenger_pipeline_status = ['MISSFLT', 'OFFLOAD']
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {
            'status_value': { '$in': messenger_pipeline_status}
            'is_deleted': False,
            'is_postponed': False,
            'is_active': True,
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            'from': 'db_shipment_status_history',
            'localField': 'pkey',
            'foreignField': 'fk_shipment_id',
            'as': 'shipment_status_history'
        }
    },

    {
        '$match': {
            'shipment_status_history': {
               '$ne': [] 
            } 
        }
    },

    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'pkey': 1,
            '_code': 1,
            'date_created': 1,
            'sender_full_name': '$sender.full_name',
            'sender_raw_address': '$sender.raw_address',
            'sender_formatted_address': '$sender.formatted_address',
            'receiver_full_name': '$receiver.full_name',
            'receiver_raw_address': '$receiver.raw_address',
            'receiver_formatted_address': '$receiver.formatted_address',
            'status_name': 1,
            'team_value': 1,
            'cs_name': 1,
            'shipment_status_history': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$shipment_status_history',
                    'as': 'shipment',
                    'cond': {
                        '$and': [
                            {'$eq': ['$$shipment.fk_shipment_id', fk_user_id]},
                            {'$in': ['$$shipment.status_value', assigned_status]},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },

    {
        '$unwind': '$shipment_status_history'
    },

    {
        '$sort': {
            'shipment_status_history.rec_timestamp': -1,
        }
    },

    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$pkey',
            'doc': {
                '$first': '$$CURRENT'
            }
        }
    },

    {
        '$unwind': '$doc'
    },

    { # last projection, I promise
        '$project': {
            '_id': '$doc.id',
            'pkey': '$doc.pkey',
            '_code': '$doc._code',
            'date_created': '$doc.date_created',
            'sender_full_name': '$doc.sender_full_name',
            'sender_raw_address': '$doc.sender_raw_address',
            'sender_formatted_address': '$doc.sender_formatted_address',
            'receiver_full_name': '$doc.receiver_full_name',
            'receiver_raw_address': '$doc.receiver_raw_address',
            'receiver_formatted_address': '$doc.receiver_formatted_address',
            'status_name': '$doc.status_name',
            'team_value': '$doc.team_value',
            'cs_name': '$doc.cs_name',
            'fk_messenger_id': '$doc.shipment_status_history.fk_shipment_id'
        }
    },
]

res = db.db_shipment.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Can I use this in mongo version 3.6 I just read that the lookup syntax on mongo version lower than 3.6 has different syntax and my query is for lower version of mongo.

Comment: AFAIU, the lookup query is compatible with version 3.6.

Comment: I think this query sorts all the shipment, what Im trying to do is sort only the data inside shipment status history collection and limit it to one then get that record["fk_messenger_id"] and put it to the shipment rec

Comment: I created a work around it could be seen here https://pastebin.com/FFEaJW2n, it works but I think if I have a lot of data it will become slow.

Comment: Another question dude, what will happen if the shipment didn't find a record in db_shipment status history?  What is the nature of mongoDB when it comes to this point? Will it stop and send error?

Comment: So the first aggregation pipeline was valid for Mongo 3.6, the other pipeline should work for older Mongo versions.

If it doesn't find a match you get an empty list back as the result of the aggregration